# how to solve extension, theme, app add to chrome error network_failed in vmware

Tags: google-chrome-extension, vmware

When I try to add any extension, theme or app from chrome webstore (https://chrome.google.com/webstore) to chrome on VMWare, it gives me all the same error.

*An Error has Occured.
NETWORK_FAILED*

I don't know how to fix it and because the normal chrome, I mean not on VMWare, acts normally, so I guess it's the VMWare issue. 
Please let me know how to fix and add to chrome successfully on VMWare.

Comment: It could be due to a third party software blocking the installation or have you tried to reinstall Chrome already?

Comment: As I wrote before, it happens on VMWare, and the same chrome in real device acts correctly.

Comment: Have you tried to enable NPAPI in `chrome://flags/#enable-npapi`?

Comment: @gui47 What does it have to do with anything?

Comment: @Xan Just make sure if VMware has anything involved with NPAPI.

Comment: Wow, It acts for me!!!

Comment: Really Thanks to Gui47 !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comment, Google has removed NPAPI support for some time now. Since the VMware requires NPAPI, so that it will break and reproduce the error. However Google has provided an override to enable NPAPI support by simply clicking `"Enable"` in the `chrome://flags/#enable-npapi` page. Glad it helps!

Comment: I'm still puzzled over "VMware requires NPAPI", can you explain a bit?